# Substitution in html file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, html

My awk script reads records from `file1`, finds the same records in `file2` and substitutes alternate positions (of the record) with a defined symbol in that. But few of the values are not getting substituted as desired. Only the first instance of the word is getting substituted, eg

- `TYTYTY` into `T##Y##`
- `TYTYTYGGHG` into `T##Y##GGHG`
- `LEFT` into `L##T`
- `LEFT NAME` into `L##T NAME`

Expected output is given below.

My code-

```
awk ' FNR==NR
{
if ($0 in word)
next
word[$0]=$0
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
 {
   old=$i
   new=""
   while (old) {
         len=length(old)
         new=new substr(old,1,1) substr("##",1,len-1)
         old=substr(old,4)
       }
      id=index(word[$0],$i)
      word[$0]=substr(word[$0],1,id-1) new substr(word[$0],id+length($i))
  }
 next
}

{
 for (i in word)
 {
  regex = "\\<" i "\\>"
  gsub(regex, ext[i])
  #id=index($0,i)
  #while(id>0) {
  #$0=substr($0,1,id-1) word[i] substr($0,id+length(word[i])) 
  #id=index($0,i)
 }
}
print 
}' records test.html > output.html
```

```
$ cat records

LEFT NAME
LEFT NAME 2
LEFT 
LEFT 123
TYTYTYGGHG
TYTYTY    
AB 8263
AB SCENARIO DEBUG
AB 8263 SCENARIO DEBUG
```

$ cat test.html

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">TabA</span><table>
<tr class="column">
 <td>LEFT NAME</td>
 <td>LEFT</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>LEFT NAME 2</td>
 <td>LEFT 123</td>
 <td>TYTYTYGGHG</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>TYTYTY</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>AB 8263</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>AB SCENARIO DEBUG</td>
<td>AB 8263 SCENARIO DEBUG</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

desired op -

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">TabA</span><table>
<tr class="column">
 <td>L##T N##E</td>
 <td>L##T</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>L##T N##E 2</td>
 <td>L##T 1##</td>
 <td>T##Y##G##G</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>T##Y##</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>A# 8##3</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>A# S##N##I# D##U#</td>
<td>A# 8##3 S##N##I# D##U#</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Current output -

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">TabA</span><table>
<tr class="column">
 <td>L##T NAME</td>
 <td>L##T</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>L##T NAME 2</td>
 <td>L##T 123</td>
 <td>T##Y##GGHG</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>T##Y##</td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>A# 8##3</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>A# S##N##I# D##U#</td>
<td>A# 8##3 SCENARIO DEBUG</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this isn't a dupe, although https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375020/why-the-output-of-array-using-awk-is-not-in-right-order comes pretty close.

TLDR: **awk arrays are not ordered** (in general)

When you iterate over an array in awk using e.g. `for (i in word)` the order that the 'index' values (aka subscripts or keys) are returned is **unspecified** by [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html); traditionally these arrrays are implemented as a hashtable and iterated in the order of that hashtable, which is some hashcode modulo some value, possibly modified or re-hashed in case of collision (so-called 'closed hashing'). This is NOT the same as the order the entries/keys were inserted, and usually it is deterministic but complicated enough to appear random from the point of view of a human.

Thus in your example, it is quite possible, depending on what awk you use and your exact data, for the `for` loop to process the entry for `LEFT` before it processes `LEFT NAME`; as a result a line containing `LEFT NAME` matches `LEFT` and is changed to `L##T NAME`, and subsequently when the loop tries `LEFT NAME` that does NOT match so the line isn't further changed. Similarly `TYTYTY` is processed first after which `TYTYTYGGHG` doesn't match, and `AB 8263` is processed first after which `AB 8263 SCENARIO DEBUG` doesn't match. Running on a different awk or with different file1 data is very likely to produce different orders and thus different results; running in a different environment may do so.

Also in your `FNR==NR` (i.e. file1) branch, `new-new substr(old,1,1) substr("##",1,len-1)` needs to be `=` not `-`. Personally I'd find it bit more natural to make that sub-loop

```
    old=$i; new=""; for(c=1; c<=length(old); c++) new = new (c%3==1? substr(old,c,1): "#")
```

although the difference is minor. Although you should be aware your sub-loop, if any word in file1 consists exactly of one or more `0` digits, optionally preceded by `+` or `-` and optionally followed by `e` and any digits, will change that to an empty string, not a same-length masked version.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dave. If not awk, what would be the better way to achieve the desired result in this case?

Comment: I tried using word boundary to substitute the values using gsub (updated code) still its not producing the desired op.